# How to remove from the list the items that have parents in the same list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Item>`.

How can I remove items that have parents in the same list using LINQ?

If it is possible I prefer method chain expression.

Item definition:

```
public class Item {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean remove items that have the same `ParentId`?

Comment: For all those who use "RemoveAll" it will fail. you have to build a new list of the relevant Items and then replace the list. Because you may remove Item 'a' which it's the parent of item 'b' before you check if 'b' should be removed.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Thanks for pointing out that RemoveAll could fail for trees.

Comment: Idrees - If any answer here solve your problem please 'approve' it, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @RoeeGavirel for your code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Children = List.Where(child => List.Any(parent => parent.Id == child.ParentID)).ToList();
List.RemoveAll(child => Children.Contains(child));
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, ParentId = 2 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 2, ParentId = 0 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 3, ParentId = 0 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 4, ParentId = 1 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 5, ParentId = 1 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 6, ParentId = 4 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 7, ParentId = 4 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 8, ParentId = 4 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 9, ParentId = 4 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 10, ParentId = 4 });
items.Add(new Item() { Id = 11, ParentId = 4 });

var shouldBeRemove =
    (from i in items
     where items.Any(input => input.Id == i.ParentId)
     select i).ToList();

items.RemoveAll(input => shouldBeRemove.Contains(input));

//Those who remain
//item with Id = 2
//item with Id = 3
```

Comment: Fail. if for Id-6 the parent is 4 it wouldn't be removed cause Id-4 will be removed before the check.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Have you ever tried your thought? I test it and it works

Comment: I did, seeing you change your answer you did also (-: --> I changed the (-1) to (+1)

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Intersting. It was working in that case you said! but with this new items it didn't. So your thought was correct. But can you explain why it works in the first case. (when I set the `parentId` of the item with id=6 to 4)

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the optimization of the compiler: running the Linq in multithreading and by "chance" it didn't failed the first case.